# While loop JOptionPane issues

Tags: java, swing, loops

Ok - I know that I am fairly close to the solution but need a nudge in the right direction. I need the user to hit YES and the program to begin asking the question again.

After execution, I get the following errors

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 1  at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown
>   Source)   at Vowel3.main(Vowel3.java:49)

```
// java class for Panel I/O
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

// declaration of the class
public class Vowel33
{

    // declaration of main program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    // objects used to store data
    String input_string = null;
    int a_count = 0;
    int e_count = 0;
    int i_count = 0;
    int o_count = 0;
    int u_count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int yes = 0;

    // 1. display a descriptive message
    String display_message = "This program asks the user for a sentence,\n" 
        + "searches the sentence for all vowels,\n"
        + "and displays the number of times each"
        + "vowel appears in the sentence";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, display_message, "Lab 3 Description", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



    // 4. visit each String posotion

     do{

        // 3. input the character string

        input_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the sentence to search");

        // 5.  if position i of String is a vowel
        // 6.  increase the appropriate vowel counter
        if (input_string.charAt(i) == 'a' || input_string.charAt(i) == 'A')
        a_count++;

        else if (input_string.charAt(i) == 'e' || input_string.charAt(i) == 'E')
        e_count++;

        else if (input_string.charAt(i) == 'i' || input_string.charAt(i) == 'I')
        i_count++;

        else if (input_string.charAt(i) == 'o' || input_string.charAt(i) == 'O')
        o_count++;

        else if (input_string.charAt(i) == 'u' || input_string.charAt(i) == 'U')
        u_count++;

        i++;

        String display_message1 = input_string                                      // 7. display the String
        + "\n\n" + "has " + input_string.length() + " characters.\n\n"          // 8. display the number of characters
        + "There are \n" 
        + a_count + " a's,\n"                                                   // 9. disaply the number of each vowel
        + e_count + " e's,\n"
        + i_count + " i's,\n"
        + o_count + " o's, and\n"
        + u_count + " u's.\n\n";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, display_message1, "Lab 3 Description", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        yes = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to enter another string?\n\n", "Extra Credit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    }   while (i < input_string.length());

            if (i == input_string.length())
            {
                yes = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to enter another string?\n\n", "Extra Credit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (yes == 1)
                {
                    input_string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the sentence to search");
                }
            }






    } // end of main
} // end of the class
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have a condition where the loop can still be executed if *yes* is 0.  Since *yes* is never redefined from what I can see, you basically have an infinite loop and your code will error out when i exits the bounds of your string's length.

Also not sure why you have two JOptionPanes at the bottom of the loop (which would execute x times where x = input_string.length())

Consider something like:

```
if(i == input_string.length()) {
    //ask the user if they want to enter another string
    if(the user selected yes){
        yes = 1;
        //instantiate again with new input_string
    }
}
```

Another note: Assuming you want to show a message asking if the user wants to enter another string once you've finished iterating through their first entry, it seems moot to have the *yes* variable and condition.

Comment: Thanks - I made changes. I am getting there. I don't have any errors anymore but the loop stops prematurely.

Comment: Trace the execution and/or debug and find out why it is executing early.  Particularly, pay attention to how many times the loop executes in relation to the length of the input string.  On the last execution of the loop (at the end of the loop), you should print out the total vowel count and ask if the user wants to enter another string.  If the user selects yes, set the new input_string, reset your counts and your i variable, and the loop will continue again.